# TINY QUESTION what mics are used in a video?

Tags: microphone

here's the link to gorgeous accordion sounds:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an AKG C 3000

[image]

If you are after this sound , take mic placement under consideration & mix too!

Mics dont just magically sound good! :D

Comment: Agreed, the tell-tale red band is visible on the middle mic.

Comment: Ohh thanks alot! I tried to record my bayan with behringer c2 stereo pair (small diaphragm condensers, 70 bucks) and with a single AKG perception 100 (large diaphragm condenser, 100 bucks). The difference was huge - AKG sounded more wide (even in mono!), with deeper and more gorgeous sound, bass was more present. C2's sounded relatively thin. 



Do you think AKG C3000 will sound even better? :) How much?

Comment: c3000 has a good bass response , i use it to record kicks sometimes when i want a more detailed/open sound , i think it's a relatively good microphone , but never recorded a bayan with it :)